# Display All Top Child Categories / Taxonomy

Tags: wp-query, categories

I want to display the top 10 child taxonomies, no parent.

This code gets 1 top parent taxonomy, then only displays it's 10 children. I would like to grab top 10 child taxonomies of all parents of taxonomy.

By top, I mean most populated of course.

```
<?php     
wp_list_categories('number=10&show_count=0&orderby=count&order=DESC&title_li=&hierarchical=0&taxonomy=cars-by') 
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe you have to use this

```
$categories=get_categories(
    array( 'parent' => $cat->cat_ID )
);
```

Then, in a loop, display this array because you can't do it with an `echo`

```
foreach ($categories as $c) {
    var_dump($c);
    // what you really want instead of var_dump is something to
    // to create markup-- list items maybe, For example...
    echo '<li>'.$c->cat_name.'</li>';
}
```

Comment: I am a bit confused, as to what loop to place the second part in. I am just wanting to display the top 10 child taxonomy links.